# How to find the missing appendices from the Anathem audiobook?

Tags: neal-stephenson, anathem, audio-book

I've listened to *[Anathem](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Anathem-Neal-Stephenson/dp/1843549174/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1453824948&sr=8-1&keywords=anathem)* by Neal Stephenson on Audible AudioBook.

While browsing in my local bookshop the other day I picked up a copy of the book and had a flick through. It turns out that there are a number of appendices at the end of the print copy of the book that go into some detail about some of the theories in the book, complete with diagrams etc.

Now, these appendices don't appear in the audiobook version so, is there a way that I can get hold of them and read them without a) buying the book (hey, I've already bought the audiobook) or b) spending an afternoon reading them in the bookshop?

I'd thought of getting it via a local library but it's unlikely that our local library would have a copy and ordering it is a little inconvenient.

Any ideas?

Comment: There aren't really any collections of the appendices online. [The Anathem Wiki](http://anathem.wikia.com/wiki/Anathem_Wiki) has some of that info, but not the diagrams. Your best bet may seeing if your library has a copy, or even an e-library where it's more likely to be available, or buying a used copy for a couple bucks on Amazon.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because shopping questions are off-topic. OP can source the diagrams legitimately by buying the books.